# Distinction between a dinner party and a pop up restaurant

Tags: california, restaurants

**Background:** I live in Alameda County, CA. I spent the last three years intently pursuing a cooking hobby, and believe I have gotten pretty good at it. I am interested in practicing cooking for a larger crowd. I am not interested in making a living (or any money, really) off my cooking.

**Question:** Is it legal for me to throw a dinner party for, say, ten to twenty friends, even if I ask them to pay their share of the cost of the menu? Can I do this with some regularity (ie. monthly?). Do things change if I allow them to invite *their* friends, who I might not know? What scale or details would require me to apply for relevant licenses (and what are they)?

Answer (score 1):

Most such regulations kick in at the point where it is a *business*, i.e. you are actually making money. Just like you can give a lift to a friend and split the fuel costs without needing a taxi license, you can make food for friends (however loosely defined) and split the ingredient costs without needing a restaurant license. If you charge enough that you can buy the ingredients and still have something left over then its a business and you need a license.